# C language - Use constant variable in preprocessor directive

Tags: ios, c, sqlite, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I'm trying to use the sqlite3 C library for our iOS app, and so I've included the sqilte3.c file into my project (this one http://goo.gl/BcIChe). When I build the project, I've only one error, but several times :

```
Use of undeclared identifier sqlite3one
```

I discovered that sqlite3one is used like this :

```
SQLITE_PRIVATE const int sqlite3one;
# define SQLITE_BIGENDIAN    (*(char *)(&sqlite3one)==0)
# define SQLITE_LITTLEENDIAN (*(char *)(&sqlite3one)==1)
# define SQLITE_UTF16NATIVE (SQLITE_BIGENDIAN ? SQLITE_UTF16BE : SQLITE_UTF16LE)
```

And so, when I use the SQLITE_UTF16NATIVE directive, the error occurs. I suspect that the sqlite3one constant is not here at the preprocessor compile time, and so it can't resolve SQLITE_BIGENDIAN, SQLITE_LITTLEENDIAN and so on.

My question is : can we use constant variable in preprocessor directive like this ? Have you another solution about this ?

Many thanks

**EDIT** : Oh, I resolved it, it was just a mistake of the library (which I have imported as it stands), the sqlite3one constant was not declared in the appropriate #ifdef section ;)

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: The preprocessor doesn't *resolve* anything. With macros (like `SQLITE_UTF16NATIVE`) it just *replaces* the macro invocation with the body of the macro. In your case it will be replaced by `((*(char *)(&sqlite3one)==0) ? <something> : <something else>)`, which is then fed to the compiler.

Comment: You mention `squlite3one` thrice. Are you sure you didn't simply use the wrong identifier, since it should be `sqlite3one`, i.e. without the `u`. The compiler cannot know you want to use `sqlite3one` if you misspell it.

Comment: Just a mistake ;) I edited my question.

Comment: OP: you seem to have ignored the comment from @JoachimPileborg.  You need to follow-up on it...